# Why do we consider the + |V| in big-O notation in the time complexity of BFS

Tags: graphs, big-o-notation

It is agreed upon that the time complexity of BFS is $O(|V| + |E|)$.
Breath first search usually is used within a connected component. The connected component with the least $|E|$ given a fixed $|V|$ is a tree graph where $|E| = |N| - 1$. Therefore $O(|E|) \ge O(|V|)$ given a connected component.
Why is the runtime complexity of BFS not $O(|E|)$ instead of $O(|V| + |E|)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any graph, the BFS is usually run using a boolean array to check if a vertex has been previously explored or not. The boolean array will always be created of size $n = |V|$. Even if the graph is not connected, you will need to create this array of size $|V|$, and in the general case, the graph does not necessarily verify $|E| \geqslant |V|$.

That is the reason why we consider a complexity of $\mathcal{O}(|E| + |V|)$ and not only $\mathcal{O}(|E|)$.

Comment: Would it be safe to say that the time complexity of BFS is O(|E|) if the assumption of the graph being connected is met?

Comment: If the graph is connected then $|E| \ge |V|-1$, hence $|E| \in \Omega(|V|)$ and $O(|E|+|V|) = O(|E|)$.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to create a BFS running at $O(|E|)$ time in general, but it is not guaranteed to visit every node (it will not visits the nodes that aren't path-connected to the starting node)